# systemd: Stop all OpenVPN processes

Tags: systemd, openvpn

Just started using systemd and need to stop and start OpenVPN.

I can successfully start OpenVPN with this for example:

```
systemctl start openvpn@vpn1.service
```

and can stop it with:

```
systemctl stop openvpn@vpn1.service
```

However I'd like to be able to stop openvpn within a script without having to know which VPN is currently connected. Previously I would use:

```
service stop openvpn
```

Is this possible using systemctl?

Comment: `systemctl stop openvpn.service` doesn't work?

Comment: Nope: Failed to stop openvpn.service: Unit openvpn.service not loaded

Comment: The questioner has no unit named `openvpn.service`.  The question names the units that _do_ exist.  Welcome to the concept of _template units_.  [Template units are how people use OpenVPN with systemd.](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=744244#c2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use patterns (including [shell globs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob)) with `systemctl` commands. See `man systemctl`:

> shell-style globs will be matched against currently loaded units; literal unit names, with or without a suffix, will be treated
>        as in the first case. This means that literal unit names always refer to exactly one unit, but globs may match zero units and this is not considered
>        an error.
>
>        Glob patterns use fnmatch(3), so normal shell-style globbing rules are used, and "*", "?", "[]" may be used. See glob(7) for more details. The
>        patterns are matched against the names of currently loaded units, and patterns which do not match anything are silently skipped. For example:
>
>                  # systemctl stop sshd@*.service
>
>        will stop all sshd@.service instances.

So, in your case: `systemctl stop openvpn*` should stop all OpenVPN services.

Comment: Indeed this does work, I had tried this before but had dismissed it when an error was shown. What I hadn't actually realised was that the error was from ZSH which was evaluating the * and returning no results. doing this in bash or like this works fine: systemctl stop 'openvpn*'